# Google Cloud Platform - Backup upload

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Google just open beta version of the Data Engineer test. They showed a sample question. Is it possible to get a propper explanation to get the solution.

Your company is moving daily database backups to the cloud. Each backup is 10 TB. You have a 1 Gbps connection to Google Cloud. You want to minimize cost. How much additional bandwidth do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Brandon for your answer, apparently the answer of the question is just a unit conversion and a division.

To calculate the time uploading the data you divide the amount of data over the connection speed.

10TB/1Gbps=22.22hours

taking into account that the data is measured in bytes and the speed is in bits. After this is common to add a 10% due to connection speed fluctuations.

24.44hours

The answer is more than a day, reason that makes you think you will need to increase your connection speed to 2Gbps, in order to have an upload time of 12.22hours.

Answer (score 2):

I don't work on this test or have any special knowledge of the canonically "right" answer, but I do know some basic algebra, so let's take a stab at this:

Each backup is 10 Terabytes. They're daily backups, which means we need to upload at least one backup per day. 10 Terabytes per day [is 0.926 Gbps](https://www.google.com/#q=10+terabytes+per+day+to+Gbps), which means we already have just barely enough bandwidth.

Of course, in practice, we probably need more bandwidth. We have a grand total of 1 Gbps to work with, and we're probably doing other things with it as well. Also, we would likely want to account for a possibility that one of our uploads might fail for some reason. And do we really want our daily uploads to be almost an entire extra day behind? Also, how often is a 1 Gbps connection really capable of achieving more than 92% of its promised capacity?